# Is it possible to draw history from paypal?

Tags: paypal

I want to write a script which once a day connects to my paypal and get all orders from it.

I didn't find anything on thier api that would be helpful.
is it doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two APIs can get transaction details:
1. TransactionSearch 
Refer to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/
2. GetTransactionDetails 
Refer to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/

You can take a look at these materials, hope these information could be helpful.

Comment: You can refer to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_searchRetrieveTransactionData-curl-etc/?mark=TransactionSearch

Comment: @ZhaoSmanta  I meant for an actual script which connects to paypal and print the results (say to file) ?

Comment: You can find some sample via google. such as http://blog.scrobbld.com/paypal/the-paypal-api-and-php/

Comment: @ZhaoSmanta what did you search? I never get good results... thank you for your link but i don't know php... if I can find python guide it would be great.

Comment: If you use python, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677494/paypal-transactionsearch-using-python  maybe helpful. Try search 'paypal transactionsearch python' via google. :)

Comment: @ZhaoSmanta thank you but its unclear.. the code doesn't make scene and the packages used there are no where to be found... I guess an example of working POST request to paypal history isn't easily found.   I'll accept the answer for people that the PHP code might help them...