# How to set up Paypal to connect with python

Tags: python, paypal

I'm writing a python script that needs to connect my PayPal account and copy order information.

The paypal API gives examples how to get the orders information https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#retrieve-an-order but it doesn't explain how to connect PayPal using python.

How do I make the initial connect to Paypal?

I tried this code: [Paypal Transactionsearch using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677494/paypal-transactionsearch-using-python) using Python it doesn't work. I can't find any reference for the imports which he uses.

Most of guides that I found are how to integrate PayPal into web site. That is not what i'm after...

Basically I want (final goal) to write a script that does that: http://www.clovercitysells.com/ebook/csv-export.pdf  an export of orders by specific criteria to somewhere else (file,DB etc..)

Comment: I'm sure you asked this question earlier, then deleted it...

Answer (score 2):

On the right column of https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api , you see a list of lanugage tab. Just select Python, and there is a link underneath. : https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK

README.md give you step by step guide.

Comment: The REAME explain how to do payments, how to proccess orders.. this is not what I'm after... Look here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_searchRetrieveTransactionData-curl-etc/?mark=TransactionSearch    This is exactly what I need.. user name, passowrd and the function to run. However this is not python, and I don't understand how do implement it in python script. If an SDK is needed why they are not using it there?

Comment: If you git clone the paypal Python SDK , you can use fgrep -lR "keywords" to search for matching function keyword shown in the REST example (it seems they use camelcase to name all those function/modules). There is examples under https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK/tree/master/samples

Comment: I still don't get it. Can you please explain why PHP doesn't need PayPal SDK while python do? If I want a red background image I can do that with Paint, I won't install PhotoShop for it. I'm looking for something very small... the SDK is huge and it also doesn't really give me the solution. I looked over the examples. Didn't find what i'm after. the `Find` method is for a specific transaction. and I still don't see where user name and password go.

Comment: What are you going on about? There is php sdk where mootmoot said to look for python. Have you actually looked at anything other than the exact place mootmoot suggested? Maybe the sdks haven't implemented orders. Sometimes life only gives you lemons and rather than moaning about it you should make lemonade with what you get. Start by learning more about rest apis - i strongly suggest using the requests library and sessions.